# React Todo App - typeof a props is not as I expect

Tags: reactjs, object, jsx, react-props

I am building React Todo app. However, I can't understand how todos type became **object?** In the *App.js*, we set it an array. In the *Form.js* we set
`setTodos([...todos, { text: inputText, id: Math.random() * 1000 }]);` I didn't understand what is going on in this line. Could you please help?

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
//Importing Components
import Form from "./components/Form";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";

function App() {
 const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
 const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
 return (
   <div className="App">
     <header>
       <h1>Hitay's Todo List</h1>
     </header>
     <Form
       todos={todos}
       setTodos={setTodos}
       inputText={inputText}
       setInputText={setInputText}
     />
     <TodoList todos={todos} />
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Form = ({ inputText, setInputText, todos, setTodos }) => {
 //Here I can write JavaScript code and Function
 const inputTextHandler = (e) => {
   setInputText(e.target.value);
 };
 const submitTodoHandler = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   setTodos([...todos, { text: inputText, id: Math.random() * 1000 }]);
   setInputText("");
 };
 return (
   <form>
     <input
       value={inputText}
       onChange={inputTextHandler}
       type="text"
       className="todo-input"
     />
     <button onClick={submitTodoHandler} className="todo-button" type="submit">
       <i className="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
     </button>
   </form>
 );
};

export default Form;
```

**TodoList.js**

```
import React from "react";
//Import Components
import Todo from "./Todo";

const TodoList = ({ todos }) => {
  console.log(typeof todos); //object??
  return (
    <div className="todo-container">
      <ul className="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: todos is array of objects. But one single todo is object, what part did you not understand exactly? can you clearify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todos is array of objects. But one single todo is an object. todos looks like this normally;

```
 todos = [
{ text: "work", id: 12314 },
{ text: "eat", id: 12321414 },
{ text: "drink", id: 12311234 },
]
```

The line you showed there `setTodos([...todos, { text: inputText, id: Math.random() * 1000 }]);` you are getting all the todos and spreading into new array with spread opearator ( `...todos` ). Then you add your new todo inside of it.

Comment: Thank you,now I see. Teşekkür ediyorum :)

Comment: Hi! sorry for interrupting. But typeof(todos) is not object because it's an array of objects. Typeof all arrays in js(even empty arrays) are objects

Comment: pls check this link (https://jsfiddle.net/8fh4x3ap/). As you can see, even the typeof empty array is `object`. Because it's not a primitive

Comment: @alisasani yes but she wasn't asking that, she was thinking todos becoming an object as a state, while they set it as an array initally. but that wasn't the case. what you're talking about is a litle bit deeper for this question

Comment: @hitayco happy coding, rica ederim :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's working as expected as the typeof array in javascript is an object.

According to [this link](https://dev.to/pestrinmarco/typeof-array-is-an-object-in-javascript-1p6k#:%7E:text=This%20because%20in%20javascript%20all,use%20isArray%20method%20of%20Array.&text=and%20the%20result%20will%20be%20the%20same%20as%20the%20previous%20one.):

> This because in javascript all derived data type is always a type
> object. Included functions and array.

If you want to check whether a variable is array or not, you can use `Array.isArray` as below:

```
Array.isArray(todos);
```

Comment: oh yes, I forgot about it, thank you for your comment!!